# Data change inside Service does not update the Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, angularjs-scope

I am storing my data inside Angular service (to share across controllers) and provide a function to update it:

```
.factory('DataManager', function($rootScope){
  var _json = {init: 'from DataManager'};

  return {
    json: _json,

    changeTo: function (newVal) {
      _json = newVal;      
      console.log("Changing to ", _json);
    }
  };

})
```

Then I simply pull the data into controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function(DataManager){
  var MC = this;

  MC.json = DataManager.json;
  MC.changeTo = DataManager.changeTo;
})
```

The problem is - when `MC.changeTo` function is called, it does update `_json` variable inside the Service, but not in the controller!

Here is [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/veqawo/edit?html,js,output) illustrating the problem.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what is your desire out put ?

Comment: @ShailendraSharma To have a scalable data storage architecture and avoid storing in the controllers.

Comment: can you please put it into plunker, jsbin is disabled at my work

Comment: You basically have `MC.json = object1` -> `changeTo(object2)` -> `_json = object2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your code doesn't work because `_json` variable is refering to diffrent object each time. `angular.copy` copies the new object to the same reference.

```
 changeTo: function (newVal) {
          angular.copy(newVal, _json);      
          console.log("Changing to ", _json);
        }
```

Comment: No luck with this - clicks throws errors: http://jsbin.com/saveme/edit?html,js,output

Comment: So it appears `angular.copy` regards primitive strings as object indexing its characters, so `angular.copy('new', obj)` leads to `Object {0: "n", 1: "e", 2: "w"}`, not exactly what I want. I would work though, if `newVal` were an object. Regardless, the way I do indeed creates a new object, thanks!